# A small computer manufacturing company

Tags: linear-programming

any body can help me with this ?
A small computer manufacturing company forecasts the demand over the next $n$ months to be $d_i$ $i = 1, 2.... n.$ In any month it can produce $r$ units, using regular production, at a cost of $b$ dollars per unit. By using overtime, it can produce additional units at $c$ dollars per unit, where $c > b$. The firm can store units from month to month at a cost of s dollars per unit per month. Formulate the problem of determining the production schedule that minimizes cost. (Hint: See Exercise 9.)

Exercise 9) A class of piecewise linear functions can be represented as $f(x) = \max (c^Tx+ d_1, c^Tx+d_2,\ldots, c^Tx+d_p).$ For such a function $f$, consider the problem

minimize $f(x)$

subject to $Ax = b$

Show how to convert this problem to a linear programming problem.

Comment: Please write what you tried

Comment: What's Exercise 9?